# mutual exclusion using Hashtable of java

Tags: java, multithreading

hi mate i have a global Hashtable in my class, and two thread A and B that work with her.
A reads from HashTable and B write in Hashtable.. is there a problem of mutual exclusion ? i need to syncrhonize it or Hashtable class is safe ?

Comment: what is "mutual exclusion" in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hashtable` is a thread-safe implementation of the `Map` interface.

In regular put and get operations you will be safe. However, when you will iterate on it in one thread and modify its contents from another thread, you will have `ConcurrentModificationException` issues. So, when iterating, make sure you iterate on a copy of the original `Hashtable`.

Comment: so i dont have any problem of mutual exclusion ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) instead, which is a much better/faster implementation of `java.util.Map` interface.

Comment: with ConcurrentHashMap i dont have problem of mutual exclusion ?

Comment: what do you mean by "mutual exclusion"? can you elaborate this term in your question a bit

Comment: THREAD-A reads from hashtable e THREAD-B write in hashtable, i need that there arent problem

Comment: it's called [thread safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety). yes, ConcurrentHashMap is thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

It's useful to use a synchronized HashMap offered by java collections. This class is a simple wrapper and encapsulates the hashmap :

```
Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
```

Further example example is in the java docs :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html synchronizedMap

Answer (score 0):

`HashTable` gaurantees that any operation executed on it is atomic. but If you are executing multiple operations you should `synchronize` them. In below example even if `contains` and `put` are atomic but the code has a `check and act` raise condition so you need additional `synchronization` for this.

```
    if(!hashtable.contains(Object))
    {
        hashtable.put(key, value);
    }
```

Also check `Collections.synchronizedMap()` or `ConcurrentHashMap` rather than `HashTable`

Answer (score 0):

Everyone has said what can be said but this is just to complement with regards to what you call `mutual exclusion`. You are asking if there won't be such a problem. A thread-safe program must ensure that that if `threadA` is using say a block of code `block1` no other thread will access it until the thread is done. So, if I understand well what you mean by `mutual exclusion`, yes threads accessing the same synchronized (thread-safe) shared resource are mutually exclusive because they both can't access it at the same time. 
Java practically does much of the hard for you if you choose one of the proposed safe `Map` implementation. Now if your Hashtable ( or whatever else thread-safe mao you prefer ) is a shared resource, the only thing you need to take care of is the *happens-before* relation. It will be important if one thread is reading data and the other writing data. 
More can be found at [java concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) and [java concurrent package docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility)